# Creating few binaries during `go install package`

Tags: go, gnu-make

`go` tool can create a binary and place it to `GOBIN` if package contains a `main` sub package (or if package is a `main`). Is there a possibility to create a few (at least two) binaries with single `go install package` command? Meaning without using `GNU make` for this purposes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible. The usual convential is that you put your binaries into packages that have `cmd` as their last path element. People can then install all the binaries like this:

```
go get code.google.com/p/codesearch/cmd/{cindex,csearch,cgrep}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's, probably, the only way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible if all commands are under a common directory, using `go install root/...`. The trailing three dots tell the go command to do this for all packages under this directory. The same three-dots notation works for `go get` or `go build` and probably all go commands.

> An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..." wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty string and strings containing slashes. Such a pattern expands to all package directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the patterns. As a special case, x/... matches x as well as x's subdirectories. For example, net/... expands to net and packages in its subdirectories.

http://golang.org/cmd/go/